# Как отразить(флипнуть) спрайт, по оси Х, в сторону его движения?

Tags: c#, unity3d

2Д игра. Есть игрок и противник. Противник постоянно двигается к позиции игрока таким кодом:

```
private void GoToPlayer()
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
        Player.instance.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
```

Спрайт врага всегда смотрит вправо, независимо в какую сторону он двигается. В SpriteRenderer компоненте есть поле Flip, которое не сложно менять. Сложность в проверке направления движения.

Если на своём персонаже я использую такой код для движения:

```
void Update()
{
    Vector2 moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));

    moveVelocity = moveInput.normalized * Speed;
}
```

Отсюда я узнаю направление, сравнивая **moveInput** с 0, и тем самым флипаю спрайт.

**Вопрос:** А вот как это сделать у врага, используя `Vector3.MoveTowards`?

P.S сравнивать координаты персонажа и противника не вариант, как я понял, потому что они могут быть как положительными, так и отрицательными в мире Юнити.

Comment: Если враг просто двигается туда-сюда, то при начале движения нужно повернуть его вправо, если его целевая координата по X больше его нынешней координаты по X, иначе влево. У вас он напрямую зависит от позиции игрока, так что можно сравнивать позицию противника и позицию игрока. Последний абзац я не понял. В чем проблема? Поворачиваем вправо, если `Player.position.x > Enemy.position.x`

Comment: Да, это действительно помогло. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`сравнивать координаты персонажа и противника не вариант` - **вариант**! Вам нужно просто рассматривать позицию врага относительно игрока.

Если враг **правее** игрока (Enemy.X > Player.X), то враг смотрит вправо,
Иначе влево.

Если движение игрока не предсказуемо, то самый простой способ - проверять каждый кадр:

```
private void GoToPlayer()
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
    Player.instance.transform.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    
    if (transform.position.x > Player.instance.transform.position.x)
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
    else
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
}
```

> GetComponent следует кэшировать, чтобы не получать каждый кадр

> player.instance.transform тоже можно кэшировать

> Разворачивать врага можно не только флипов в рендерере, но и устанавливая отрицательный размер по Z